# dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object

Tags: python, networkmanager, d-bus

I am trying to run a script to connect to a specific wifi network, and I am getting this error. I am running archlinux lts 4.4.47-1. Any general suggestions for further reading/understanding of the problem are very appreciated, I just don't know where to look.

Comment: Your question too unspecific and as such not answerable; questions for learning material are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have dbus package intalled and running.
I don't know which is in archlinux, on ubuntu & gentoo package is dbus, and to be sure it is running: 
service dbus restart
also make sure you have python-dbus bindings installed